# Gulp 4 - Task is not running properly with Browsersync

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp, browser-sync

- [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com) Local v4.0.2, CLI v2.3.0
- [Browsersync](https://browsersync.io) v2.26.13

**`gulpfile.js`**:

```js
'use strict'

const gulp        = require('gulp')
const concat      = require('gulp-concat')
const babel       = require('gulp-babel')
const uglify      = require('gulp-uglify')
const browserSync = require('browser-sync')

require('dotenv').config()

const server = browserSync.create()

function js() {
    return gulp
        .src(['./resources/js/main.js', './resources/js/theme.js'])
        .pipe(
            babel({
                presets: ['@babel/env'],
            })
        )
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/js/'))
}

function serve(done) {
    server.init({
        proxy: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`,
        port: 3001,
    })
    done()
}

function reload(done) {
    server.reload()
    done()
}

function watch() {
    return gulp.watch('./resources/js/*.js', gulp.series(js, reload))
}

const dev = gulp.series(js, serve, watch)

exports.default = dev
```

This setup is pretty similar to [this example](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/minimal-browsersync-setup-with-gulp4.md) in Gulp docs.

Proxying an express server at `localhost:3000` and watching for changes to JavaScript files.

### The Problem

Browser reload not finishing up when I change any JavaScript file located at `./resources/js/`. I can see that **`js`** task is working correctly as it creates `./public/assets/js/app.min.js` file.

When I hit `gulp` command, it runs the task **`dev`** (`gulp.series(js, serve, watch)`) successfully as a default task and starts watching for changes. After I change & save a JavaScript file, `js` and `reload` tasks start to run. But browser reload is stuck and nothing else happens.

The output of my terminal when I update & save a `.js` file:

```sh
[15:39:16] Starting 'js'...
[15:39:16] Finished 'js' after 61 ms
[15:39:16] Starting 'reload'...
[15:39:16] Finished 'reload' after 2.03 ms
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
```

Answer (score 0):

- [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) v3.2.25
- [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) v4.17.1

After spending hours and hours, I finally found out that there was a problem in my node server. I was running it with [`esm`](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) loader enabled.

I was running the server like so:

```sh
nodemon -r esm app.js
```

### The Solution

Everything worked as expected when I started the express server this way:

```sh
nodemon app.js
```

However, I'm still not sure this is the best solution.

I have no idea why enabling `esm` causes the trouble and prevents Browsersync from reloading.